# Change Fontsize and boxsize in highchart R

Tags: r, highcharts, font-size

I'm trying to create an automated organiganization chart.
But it's unreadable. I would like to change the fontsize and the size of the boxes

The code is below

```
pl <- highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_title(text = 'Klarna ownership structure')%>%
  hc_caption(text = 'Ownership from left to right')%>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Runway AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Runway AB Sweden', to = 'Toplooks LCC USA', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', to = 'Larkan Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Larkan Holding AB Sweden', to = 'Larkan AB', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Larkan Holding AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Midco AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Midco AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Larkan AB', to = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Midco AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'SEQUOIA CAPITAL United Kingdom', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Silver Lake Partners USA', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Bestseller Group Denmark', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Dragoneer USA', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Permira UK', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Visa USA', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Atomico UK', to = 'Klarna Holding AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Analyzd Technologies Ltd Cyprus', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Ident Inkasso AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Australia Holding Pty Ltd Australia', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Austria GmbH Austria', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Belgium N.V Belgium', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna B.V. The Netherlands', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Germany Holding GmbH Germany', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna GmbH Germany', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Inc The United States', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Italy S.r.l. Italy', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Norge AS Norway', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Oy Finland', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna Spain S.L. Spain', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Klarna UK Limited UK', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'Search Engine Marketing Sweden AB Sweden', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Bank AB Sweden', to = 'BillPay GmbH  Germany', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Germany Holding GmbH Germany', to = 'Sofort GmbH', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Australia Holding Pty Ltd Australia', to = 'Klarna Australia Pty Ltd Australia', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Klarna Australia Holding Pty Ltd Australia', to = 'Klarna New Zealand Ltd New Zealand', weight = 1),
      list(from = 'Analyzd Technologies Ltd Cyprus', to = 'Klarna Ltd ?', weight = 1)
      ))%>%
  hc_theme(hc_theme_ft())

pl
```

How can change the font size and the size of the boxes?
tried to google it but it always is java or something else and I have not been able to convert it correctly to R.

With Regards Kristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap JavaScript code in R to use the Highcharts JS API for that purpose. You can find an article explaining how to do this here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR1AipximplJVYVQbBerc2nu7xDe3Vn7o4HOtmPMU_Ntrzf4SgLyNtc9KVk

Then use the dataLabels.style.fontSize option to change that text size:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.dataLabels.style.fontSize

Regarding changing the height of the node it is an additional option here like height. See as I did it in the demo below:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal'),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain'),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England'))
  ) %>%

hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this;
      chart.update({
        chart: {
          backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
        },
        plotOptions: {
              series: {
                  dataLabels: {
                      style: {
                        fontSize: '6px'
                    }
                },
                nodes: [{
                  id: 'Brazil',
                  height: 20
                }]
              }
            }
        })
      }
    ")
))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks!

Need to divert into another task now. But I will check it out as soon as possible!